# Questions about a multivariate timeseries forecasting model - keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, time-series

I have trouble understanding the model I'm trying to create.
I have few questions so I'll explain my model first and what I'm trying to do:

I have created sequences of data (input and ouput of the model) 7 timesteps each so the input would be the values of the days of a certain week and the output is the values of the days the following week (**so input1 of my model has an imput shape of (7,1) same as the output**). 
I also have prepared another input list that has some extra features like holiday flag and weather condition for the **following week** so the model's second input2 has the shape (7,7) each example.

This is the full model summary:

[image: full model summary]

After the lstm layers and a fully connected NN, I tried to concatenate the two inputs together, basically, I want to concatenate `input2` to the output of the layer `dense_1`.
So I'm concatenating (7,1) shape with the second input '`input_2`' of shape (7,7)

My questions:

1- The outputs of my dense layers confuse me I thought they would be in the shape (None, number of units) but they seem to be (None, 7 , number of units) there is always the 2nd dimension "7" which i don't understand.

[image: dense layers]

2- For the concatenation part, since i'm adding a 7x7 input to a 7x1 input i was expecting to have 49+7=56 units connected to the next dense layer but the number of parameters tells me it's not the case being just 14*120+120=1800

[image: concat]

3- I was thinking of having 7 units in the last layer ( 1 for each day to predict ) but had to make it 1 so it would output (7,1) and for it to work, there is something i'm clearly missing.

[image: 3rd question]

This is the code for model definition:

```
input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(7,1),name="input_1")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(120, kernel_size=5,strides=1,activation="relu",
                           padding="causal",input_shape=[7, 1])(input1)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(210, return_sequences=True),name="LSTM_1")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(210, return_sequences=True,name="LSTM_2"))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(60,activation="relu",name="dense_1_1")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30,activation="relu",name="dense_1_2")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7,name="dense_1_3")(x)

input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(7,7),name="input_2")
concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, input2],name="concat_1")
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(120,activation="selu",name="dense_2_1")(concat)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(90,activation="selu",name="dense_2_2")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(60,activation="selu",name="dense_2_3")(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = tf.keras.Model([input1, input2], output)
```

These are the dimensions of the inputs (input1 & input2) and the output

[image: dimensions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Keras docs:
https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/

> Input shape
>
> N-D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, ..., input_dim)`. The most common
> situation would be a 2D input with shape `(batch_size, input_dim)`.
>
> Output shape
>
> N-D tensor with shape: `(batch_size, ..., units)`. For instance, for a
> 2D input with shape `(batch_size, input_dim)`, the output would have
> shape `(batch_size, units)`.
>
> If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense
> computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the
> last axis of the inputs and axis 1 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot).
> For example, if input has dimensions (batch_size, d0, d1), then we
> create a kernel with shape (d1, units), and the kernel operates along
> axis 2 of the input, on every sub-tensor of shape (1, 1, d1) (there
> are batch_size * d0 such sub-tensors). The output in this case will
> have shape (batch_size, d0, units).

The input to `dense_1_1` is `(None, 7, 420)`. The Dense layer will be applied to every `[:,i,:] for in 1..7` slice of the input producing an output of size `(None, 7, 60)`

If you're expecting an output with shape `(None, 60)` you can reshape the input to `(None, 420*7)` but that would not make sense in this case since you would want to apply the Dense layer to each time slice of your input.

Comment: I understand better now but this still confuses me when you said "The Dense layer will be applied to every [:,i,:] for in 1..7 slice of the input producing an output of size (None, 7, 60)" why is the number of parameters 420*60 + 60 = 25260 I thought it should have been  (420*60 +60) * 7*, it is as if all the timesteps share the same 420 * 60 weights shouldn't it be 420 * 60 weight for each timestep, I have tried to wrap the dense_1_* layers with a TimeDistributed wrapper but the number of parameters is exactly the same?

Comment: You're correct. The timesteps do share the weights. It would make sense to apply the same transformation to each timestep because each of them represent the same features but at a different point of time. I have edited the answer to include a  snippet from the Keras Docs that may give some insight

Comment: Thanks, I think now I get that part.
Now for the concatenation part if you have any idea, lets say I change dense_1_3 to output (None,7,1) representing the value of each timestep to predict, now I want to concatenate a (7,7) input representing 7 features of the 7 days to predict so they are not really the same timesteps ,rather the timesteps of the days to predict , do you reckon flattening the (7,1) output and concatenating a (49) vector to the flattened (7) vector is the way to go instead of concatenating the (7,7) to the (7,1) ?